# Flattened SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is in SQL Server 2014.

Without changing the table structures what is the easiest way you can suggest to change this query (output shown below)

```
select 
    a.Id, a.Sku, a.lbl,
    Desc, 
    (select b.Valu where b.Attribute = 'rel') as 'rel',
    (select b.Valu where b.Attribute = 'uom') as 'uom',
    (select b.Valu where b.Attribute = 'clas') as 'clas'
from 
    items a 
join
    itemattributes b on b.id = a.id
```

Output:

```
id  sku     lbl          desc   rel     uom     clas
2   X111    X111-456789  red    NULL    NULL    C
2   X111    X111-456789  red    NULL    Cs      NULL
2   X111    X111-456789  red    3       NULL    NULL
3   X222    X222-567890  white  NULL    NULL    B
3   X222    X222-567890  white  NULL    Cs      NULL
3   X222    X222-567890  white  2       NULL    NULL
4   X333    X333-678901  blue   NULL    NULL    C
4   X333    X333-678901  blue   NULL    Ea      NULL
4   X333    X333-678901  blue   9       NULL    NULL
```

To this output:

```
id  sku     lbl          desc   rel     uom     clas
2   X111    X111-456789  red    3       Cs      C
3   X222    X222-567890  white  2       Cs      B
4   X333    X333-678901  blue   9       Ea      C
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the table and indexing, I would use HLGEM's solution (below) for the best optimization.

Comment: Thanks guys.  All great input.  I've tended to find myself writing this th\e way John P. shows.  But VKP reminds me of what I've done before.  I sometimes wonder where will the multiple joins start to work against me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to group by different attribute values.

```
select a.Id 
    , a.Sku
    , a.lbl
    , [Desc]
    , max(case when b.Attribute = 'rel' then b.Valu end) as rel
    , max(case when b.Attribute = 'uom' then b.Valu end) as uom
    , max(case when b.Attribute = 'clas' then b.Valu end) as clas
from items a    
join itemattributes b   
    on b.id = a.id
group by a.Id 
    , a.Sku
    , a.lbl
    , [Desc]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
select a.Id 
    , a.Sku
    , a.lbl
    , Desc
    , rel.Valu as  'rel'
    , uom.Valu as 'uom'
    , clas.Valu as 'clas'
from items a    
join itemattributes rel   
    on rel.id = a.id and rel.Attribute = 'rel'
join itemattributes uom  
    on uom.id = a.id and uom.Attribute = 'uom'
join itemattributes clas   
    on clas.id = a.id  and clas.Attribute = 'clas'
```

This assumes you will only want records that have all three values. If this is not a true assumption, try left joins. Note I put the attribute in the join to make it easier if you have to use a left join. if you use inner joins then you could put those in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could do multiple joins:

```
select a.Id 
    , a.Sku
    , a.lbl
    , Desc
    , b.Valu as 'rel'
    , c.Valu as 'uom'
    , d.Valu as 'clas' 
from items a        
    join itemattributes b on b.id = a.id    
    join itemattributes c on c.id = a.id    
    join itemattributes d on d.id = a.id 
where b.Attribute = 'rel'   
   and c.Attribute = 'uom'  
   and d.Attribute = 'clas'
```

You should also be able to eliminate the joins altogether:

```
select a.Id 
    , a.Sku
    , a.lbl
    , Desc
    , (select b.Valu from itemattributes b where b.id = a.id and b.Attribute = 'rel') as 'rel'
    , (select b.Valu from itemattributes b where b.id = a.id and b.Attribute = 'uom') as 'uom'
    , (select b.Valu from itemattributes b where b.id = a.id and b.Attribute = 'clas') as 'clas'
from items a
```

Comment: Absolute personal preference by I would put the WHERE conditions in the Join clause for readability of queries intent and as HLGEM mentions being able to easily switch this to left joins say if an attribute type is missing.

Comment: @matt Yeah.  HLGEM gave that example.  Six one way, half dozen the other.